# Bulk API errors: Upsert on Standard Salesforce Object

Tags: java, salesforce, bulkinsert, bulkloader, bulk-load

We're using Bulk Api to upsert records for both Custom and Standard Salesforce Objects. Its working fine for custom objects but when We're trying to perform Upsert operation on a Standard Salesforce Object say: Account, the error of specifies Invalid External ID specified as:

> [AsyncApiException  exceptionCode='InvalidJob' 
>   exceptionMessage='Field name provided, Name does not match an External
>   ID, Salesforce Id, or indexed field for Account' ]

We're providing Name as an external ID through java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Account.Name` is not an external Id field! And neither is `AccountNumber` for that matter. I guess you're confused because it can be used as match field for de-duplication in "import my accounts & contacts" etc?

Here are my results, I don't think you'll get different ones:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Account.Name.getDescribe();
System.debug(f.isExternalID());  // false
System.debug(f.isUnique());      // false
System.debug(f.isIdLookup());    // false
```

You'll need to create your own Ext. Id. field if you want to use it in upserts (and fill it with data). In my org we have custom `Account_Number__c`...

Comment: Thanks eyescream for your genuine Answer. Does every Standard Salesforce Object behave in this manner in case of performing upsert operations using Bulk API? Thanks, Sanchit

Comment: I think so. As far as I know none of standard objects has any Ext ID or Unique field, it's entirely up to us how we customize them. (well OK, `User.Username` is unique but you get the idea). If you're 100% sure your acc. names will be unique - make your own `Name__c` field, setup a workflow that would fill it on `ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(Name)` and make a data fix to fill records you have so far, shouldn't be too hard :)

Comment: Thanks eyescream.. :) Now it makes sense for me to work on this further.. Thanks, Sanchit

Comment: Could be a more recent addition of Salesforce API, but the latest docs on `upsert()` say this: "On standard objects, this call can use the name of any field with the idLookup field property instead of the external ID." And IDs do have this property.